# Play MP4 in ExoPlayer the simplest way

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm new to Android Development here, and I'm having a hard time integrating and using ExoPlayer in my project. I found a lot of tutorials but as expected I am getting a lot of different approaches and most are outdated and hard to build. I found one approach that works, but the problem is, that it plays `m3u8` files. I want to make Exoplayer play `mp4` files (from a URL). Here is the code for the Exoplayer demo that works for me but only plays `m3u8` files.

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null
private var playbackPosition = 0L
private var playWhenReady = true

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    )
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    preparePlayer()
}

private fun preparePlayer() {
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
    exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = true
    binding.playerView.player = exoPlayer
    val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
    val mediaItem =
        MediaItem.fromUri(URL)
    val mediaSource =
        HlsMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem)
    exoPlayer?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
    exoPlayer?.seekTo(playbackPosition)
    exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
    exoPlayer?.prepare()
}

private fun releasePlayer() {
    exoPlayer?.let { player ->
        playbackPosition = player.currentPosition
        playWhenReady = player.playWhenReady
        player.release()
        exoPlayer = null
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    releasePlayer()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    releasePlayer()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    releasePlayer()
}

companion object {
    const val URL =
        "sample m3u8 file URL here"
}
```

Please help me tweak or make the code play `mp4` files. Please bare with me I'm totally new to Android development and ExoPlayer. I will greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: What error do you get in the logs and on screen when you use an mp4 url rather than the m3u8 one?

Comment: Null exception on url if I use MP4 and use MIMEType in mediaitem.

Answer (score 3):

For each media type you should use the proper `MediaSource` in exoplayer. For MP4 file you need to use `ProgressiveMediaSource` as stated [here](https://exoplayer.dev/media-sources.html), but in your code you are using `HlsMediaSource` which is only suitable for hls (m3u8) files.

Answer (score 2):

You should make like this:

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null
private var playbackPosition = 0L
private var playWhenReady = true

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    )
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    preparePlayer()
}

private fun preparePlayer() {
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
    exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = true
    binding.playerView.player = exoPlayer
    val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
    val mediaItem =
        MediaItem.fromUri(URL)
    val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(mediaItem)
    exoPlayer?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
    exoPlayer?.seekTo(playbackPosition)
    exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
    exoPlayer?.prepare()
}

private fun releasePlayer() {
    exoPlayer?.let { player ->
        playbackPosition = player.currentPosition
        playWhenReady = player.playWhenReady
        player.release()
        exoPlayer = null
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    releasePlayer()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    releasePlayer()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    releasePlayer()
}

companion object {
    const val URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
}
```